# Joda-time library: issue in Json schema validation

Tags: java, jodatime, json-schema-validator

I  am trying to implement json schema validation for my web application using **`joda-time`** lib. Current weblogic version  is 10.3.6. Please find the weblogic .xml entry for the same:

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.joda.time.*</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>
      </wls:container-descriptor>
```

I am getting below error -:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFixedDecimal(Lorg/joda/time/DateTimeFieldType;I)Lorg/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
      at com.github.fge.jsonschema.format.common.DateTimeAttribute.<clinit>(DateTimeAttribute.java:56)
      at com.github.fge.jsonschema.library.format.CommonFormatAttributesDictionary.<clinit>(CommonFormatAttributesDictionary.java:52)
      at com.github.fge.jsonschema.library.format.DraftV3FormatAttributesDictionary.<clinit>(DraftV3FormatAttributesDictionary.java:47)
      at com.github.fge.jsonschema.library.DraftV3Library.<clinit>(DraftV3Library.java:32)
      at com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfigurationBuilder.<clinit>(ValidationConfigurationBuilder.java:63)
```

Please help me getting the configuration right. Let me know if more information needed. Thanks.